# What is the growlnotify -c option?

Tags: macos, parameters, growl, growlnotify

If `growlnotify -h`:

```
Usage: growlnotify [-hsvuwc] [-i ext] [-I filepath] [--image filepath]
                   [-a appname] [-p priority] [-H host] [-P password]
                   [-n name] [-A method] [--html] [-m message] [-t] [--url url]
                   [title]
```

But the meaning of `c` in `[-hsvuwc]` is not described. What could it be?

### Update:

the official man page installed with the program **has no description** of a c option. Several online man pages I found has neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
-c,--crypt      Encrypt UDP notifications. By default, UDP notifications are sent unencrypted.
```

Comment: It may be related to what version you have. I just Googled the man page though as I don't have `growlnotify` installed.

Comment: http://scottlab.ucsc.edu/Library/init/zsh/man/html/growlnotify.html is the first one in the search, actually a very old one. But I installed a fresh version from the official site - still there is an option, no description.

Answer (score 1):

`-c,--crypt      Encrypt UDP notifications.`

per `growlnotify -h` on my install.